# Basic spin-lock mutex implementation ordering

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

There is a popular spin-lock mutex version which is spreaded across the Internet and which one might encounter in the Anthony Williams book(C++ Concurrency in Action). Here it is:

```
class SpinLock
{
    std::atomic_flag locked;
public:
    SpinLock() :
        locked{ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT}
    {
    }
    void lock() 
    {
        while(locked.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    }
    void unlock() 
    {
        locked.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```

The thing I do not understand is why everybody uses `std::memory_order_acquire` for the `test_and_set` which is an RMW operation. Why is it not `std::memory_acq_rel`?
Suppose we have 2 threads simultaneously trying to acquire a lock:

```
T1: test_and_set -> ret false
T2: test_and_set -> ret false
```

The situation should be possible since we have 2 `acquire` operations which don't form any `sync with` relationship between each other. Yes, after we have unlocked the mutex we have a `release` operation which heads a subsequent `release sequence` and life becomes colorful and everyone is happy. But why is it safe before the `release sequence` is headed?

Since many people mention exactly that implementation I suppose it should work correctly. So what am I missing?

**UPDATE 1:**

I perfectly understand that the operation is atomic, that operations between `lock` and `unlock` can't go out of the critical section. This is not a problem. The problem is that I don't see how the code above prevents 2 mutexes coming into the critical section *simultaneously*. To prevent it from happening there should be *happens before* relationship between 2 `lock`s. Could someone show me, using the C++ standard notions, that the code is perfectly safe?

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok, we are close to the correct answer, I believe. I've found the following in the standard:

**[atomics.order] clause 11**

> Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value
>   (**in the modification order**) written before the write associated with
>   the read-modify-write operation.

And on this major note I could happily close the question but I still have my doubts. What about `in the modification order` part?
Standard is pretty clear about it:

**[intro.multithread] clause 8**

> All modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some
>   particular total order, called the modification order of M . If A and
>   B are modifications of an atomic object M and A **happens before**(as defined 
>   below) B, then A shall precede B in the modification order of M ,
>   which is defined below.

So according to that clause for an RMW operation to have the latest written value, the latest write operation should *happen before* the reading part or RMW operation. Which is not the case in the question. Right?

**UPDATE 3:**

I more and more think that the code for a spin lock is broken. Here is my reasoning. C++ specify 3 types of operations:

- Acquire, release, acquire-release - these are sync ops.
- Relaxed - these are no sync ops
- RMW - these are operations with "special" characteristic

Let's start with RMW and find out what so special about them. First, they are a valuable asset in forming `release sequence`, second they have a special clause([atomics.order] clause 11) cited above. Nothing else special I found.

Acquire/release are sync ops and `release sync with acquire` so forming a `happens before` relationship. Relaxed operations are just plain atomics and don't participate in the modification order at all.

What we have in our code? We have an RMW operation which uses acquire memory semantics so whenever first unlock(release) is reached it serves 2 roles:

1. It forms a `sync with` relationship with the previous `release`
2. It participates in the `release sequence`.
   But that's all true only after the first `unlock` has finished.

Before that, if we have 2+ threads which are simultaneously running our `lock` code then we can enter pass the `lock` simultaneously since 2 `acquire` operations don't form any kind of relationship. They are as unordered as relaxed operations would. Since they are unordered we can't use any special clauses about RMW operations since there is no `happens before` relationship and hence no modification order for the `locked` flag.

So either my logic is flawed or code is broken. Please, whoever knows the truth - comment on this.

Comment: Why is there no sleep(0)  in the while loop. As written we do not yield at all while spinning so we will continue to spin until our time slice is up. The may lead to poor performance especially on single core machines.

Comment: @doron, because this implementation is for showing how to use atomics not how to write good spin locks. Sure this implementation is naive but it never meant to be anything more. There is a `yield` function in C++ btw, so you need not use the `sleep(0)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Could someone show me, using the C++ standard notions, that the code is perfectly safe?

I initially had the same concerns as you. I think the key is understanding that operations on the `std::atomic_flag` variable are atomic with respect to all processors/cores. Two atomic 'test and set' operations in separate threads cannot simultaneously succeed, regardless of the memory ordering specified, since they then could not be atomic; the operation must apply to the actual variable, not a *cached local copy* (which is, I think, not even a concept in C++).

**A full chain of reasoning:**

29.7 p5 (talking about the test-and-set operation):

> Effects: Atomically sets the value pointed to by object or by this to true. Memory is affected according to the value of order. These operations are atomic read-modify-write operations (1.10).
>   Returns: Atomically, the value of the object immediately before the effects.

1.10 p6:

> All modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some particular total order, called the modification order of M ...

So, if as this case two threads attempt to lock the spinlock at the same time, one of them must be first and the other one second. We now just need to show that the second one will by necessity return that the flag was already set, thus preventing that thread from entering the critical section.

Paragraph 6 goes on to say:

> ... If A and B are modifications of an atomic object M and A happens before (as defined below) B, then A shall precede B in the modification order of M , which is defined below. [ Note: This states that the modification orders must respect the “happens before” relationship. — end note ]

There is no "happens before" relationship between the two test-and-set operations happening in the two threads, so we cannot determine which comes first in the modification order; however, due to the first sentence in p6 (which states that there is a total ordering), one must definitely come before the other. Now, from 29.3 p12:

> Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation.

This shows that the test-and-set ordered second must see the value written by the test-and-set ordered first. Any acquire/release choices do not affect this.

*Therefore, if two test-and-set operations are performed "simultaneously", they will be given an arbitrary order, and the second shall see the flag value that was set by the first.* As such the memory order constraints specified for the test-and-set operation do not matter; they are used to control ordering of writes to other variables during the period where the spinlock is acquired.

**Response to "Update 2" of the question:**

> So according to that clause for an RMW operation to have the latest written value, the latest write operation should happen before the reading part or RMW operation. Which is not the case in the question. Right?

Correct that there is no "happen before" relationship, but incorrect that an RMW operation needs such a relationship in order to be guaranteed the latest written value. The statement you list as "[atomics.order] clause 11" does not require a "happens before" relationship, just that one operation is before the other in the "modification order" for the atomic flag. Clause 8 states that there will be such an order, and it will be a total ordering:

> All modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some particular total order, called the modification order of M ...

... it then goes on to say that the total ordering must be consistent with any "happens before" relationships:

> ... If A and B are modifications of an atomic object M and A happens before (as defined below) B, then A shall precede B in the modification order of M, which is defined below.

However, in the absence of a "happens before" relationship, there is still a total ordering - it's just that this ordering has a degree of arbitrariness. That is, if there is no "happens before" relationship between A and B, then it is not specified whether A is ordered before or after B. But it must be one or the other, because there is a **particular total order**.

**Why is memory_order_acquire needed, then?**

A mutex such as a spinlock is often used to protect other, non-atomic variables and data structures. Using `memory_order_acquire` when locking the spinlock assures that a read from such variables will see the correct values (i.e. the values written by any other thread that previously held the spinlock). For the unlock, `memory_order_release` is also needed in order to allow other threads to see the written values.

The acquire/release both prevent the compiler from re-ordering reads/writes past the acquisition/release of the lock, and ensure that any necessary instructions to ensure appropriate levels of cache coherency are generated.

**Further evidence:**

First, this note from 29.3:

> Note: Atomic operations specifying memory_order_relaxed are relaxed with respect to memory ordering. Implementations must still guarantee that any given atomic access to a particular atomic object be indivisible with respect to all other atomic accesses to that object. — end note

This is essentially saying that the memory ordering specified does not affect the atomic operation itself. The access must "be indivisible with respect to all other atomic accesses" *including those from other threads*. To allow two test-and-set operations to read the same value would effectively be dividing at least one of them, so that it was no longer atomic.

Also, from 1.10 paragraph 5:

> In addition, there are relaxed atomic operations, which are not synchronization operations, and atomic read-modify-write operations, which have special characteristics.

(A test-and-set falls into this latter category) and especially:

> “Relaxed” atomic operations are not synchronization operations even though, like synchronization operations, *they cannot contribute to data races*.

(emphasis mine). A case where two threads both simultaneously executed an atomic test-and-set (and both performed the 'set' part) would be such a data race, so this text again indicates that this cannot happen.

1.10 p8:

> Note: The specifications of the synchronization operations define when one reads the value written by another. For atomic objects, the definition is clear.

It means one *thread* reads the value written by another. It says that for atomic objects the definition is clear, meaning that *no other synchronisation is necessary* - it is enough to perform the operation on the atomic object; the effect will be seen immediately by other threads.

In particular, 1.10 p19:

> [ Note: The four preceding coherence requirements effectively disallow compiler reordering of atomic operations to a single object, even if both operations are relaxed loads. This effectively makes the cache coherence
>   guarantee provided by most hardware available to C ++ atomic operations. — end note ]

Note the mention of *cache coherence* even in the presence of relaxed loads. This clearly shows that the test-and-set can only succeed in one thread at a time, since for one to fail either cache coherence is broken or the operation is not atomic.

Comment: I disagree. I don't understand why are you all talking about atomicity while it is **completely** irrelevant here. "access to a particular atomic object be indivisible with respect to all other atomic accesses to that object" - just guarantees that you can't see partly written object in the different thread. That's all. It doesn't state that if the variable is set than it will be visible in the other thread any time soon. Only **happens before** relationship guarantees it. And we don't have it in the question.

Comment: So first thread make `t-a-s`, writing the flag variable to the write buffer, and the second thread makes the same. Effectively they both entering the critical section. What would stop them from doing it? Correct behavior is not achievable without memory barrier, but according to the answers we could even used `relaxed` objects which doesn't produce barriers at all. Why so much fuss about the whole execution model then?

Comment: ""access to a particular atomic object be indivisible with respect to all other atomic accesses to that object" - just guarantees that you can't see partly written object in the different thread. That's all." - but the _test-and-set_ operation is itself atomic.  From 29.7 p5: "Effects: Atomically sets the value pointed to by object or by this to true. Memory is affected according to the value of order. These operations are atomic read-modify-write operations (1.10)."

Comment: what atomicity has to do with the visibility of the effect? Operations on `int` are atomic on x86 machines still you can see different values of the same variable on different threads. Look at my update in the answer, all this atomic stuff is really irrelevant.

Comment: @ixSci "all this atomic stuff is really irrelevant" - it's not, because "atomic" implies cache coherence, that is, a change of an atomic flag is seen immediately in other threads. See 1.10p19 (I've amended the answer to include the text)

Comment: @ixSci "So first thread make t-a-s, writing the flag variable to the write buffer, and the second thread makes the same" - the second could not possible test-and-set the flag since it was already set; the test would fail as the flag was _already set_. The operation as whole is atomic and there is an ordering imposed on the operation by 1.10p6 (quoted in the answer). Of the two test-and-set operations in the two threads, one of them must go first; the second one, necessarily, fails.

Comment: @davamc, 1.10/19(which in my version of standard is 21) talks about compiler reordering hence about *one* thread. The part of coherence relates to the rules described prior to that clause. And all prior clauses use `happens before`. If it was as you say then why would we need to specify memory operation type in `t-a-s` at all? According to your answer it is already behaves like sequentially consistent which is obviously not the case.

Comment: "Of the two test-and-set operations in the two threads, one of them must go first; the second one, necessarily, fails" that is sequentially consistent behavior which is true by default but it is not if we specify anything less restrictive.

Comment: @ixSci not so, the standard actually specifies certain ordering behavior for atomic operations, please re-read my answer as I have edited it heavily since I originally wrote it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though -- why is `mem_order_acquire` needed on a lock operation?

Comment: @davmac, sorry, but I can't agree with your logic. "But, due to the first sentence in p6, one must still come before the other in the modification order" You just torn the clause on 2 halves but you can't do it. There is no total order without "happens before" relationship. SO comments are bad for such a discussion so I can't comment all your logic. But single total order is a luxury of a sequential consistent code only. You can find more in "C++ concurrency in action" p.126(Non-sequentially consistent memory orderings").

Comment: @ixSci it's clear, right there in the text: **All modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some particular total order**, full stop. You can't just claim that the existence of this ordering requires a happens-before. Yes, I split the clause in half, but only because the 1st sentence applies to your example whereas the rest does not. The remainder of the clause is there to enforce that _if_ there is a happens before relationship, the total ordering respects it. There is even a note which says as much.

Comment: @davmac, well I see your point. I need to think about it further. Thanks for the answers, I appreciate it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I felt that the OP's question was due to a certain misunderstanding, which I have attempted to address. (In fact, the question is not "why is mem_order_acquire needed?", it is "why not mem_order_acq_rel?") However I have added a brief discussion to my answer now.

Comment: @davmac That would be so even were it not stated. If two things can overlap, then one of them must not be atomic. By definition, "atomic" operations occur all at once, and so two of them cannot overlap since they have no width.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I assume you refer to "All modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some particular total order"? That two operations don't overlap doesn't necessarily mean they must be ordered with respect to each other; I think your argument here is incomplete. Regardless, when dealing with a programming language we potentially face discrepancies between common English and the formal definition in the programming language (consider "volatile" and "static"); i.e. it's necessary to establish that "atomic" means the same thing as we think it does.

Comment: @davmac "That two operations don't overlap doesn't necessarily mean they must be ordered with respect to each other." Yes, it does. There are only three possibilities if A and B both occur: 1) A comes first. 2) B comes first. 3) Parts of A and B overlap (A is not complete before B begins and/or B is not complete before A begins). If A and B are both atomic, then 3 is impossible. This is *precisely* what atomic means -- happens all at once with no other atomic operation overlapping.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've forgotten the context of this thread (which is over 5 years old). You addressed the comment ("that would be so even if it were not stated") to me, which was either missing the point that I was using the fact it *is* stated as evidence, or was addressed to the wrong person. You're correct that two atomic operations on the same object can't overlap. I would still prefer to avoid the assumption that operations on an "atomic object" are necessarily atomic operations without evidence from the standard (which exists). Why rely on interpretation when it's right there in the text?

Answer (score 14):

I think what you're missing is that `test_and_set` is atomic, period. There is no memory ordering setting that makes this operation not atomic. If all we needed was an atomic test and set, we could specify any memory ordering.

However, in this case, we need more than just an atomic "test and set" operation. We need to ensure that memory operations we performed after we confirmed that the lock was ours to take aren't re-ordered to before we observed the mutex to be unlocked. (Because those operations won't be atomic operations.)

Consider:

1. Some reads of data not protected by the mutex.
2. Some writes to data not protected by the mutex.
3. We try to lock the mutex.
4. We see the mutex as locked and fail to lock it.
5. We see the mutex as unlocked and atomically lock it.
6. Some reads of data protected by the mutex.
7. Some writes to data protected by the mutex.

What is the one thing that must not happen? It's that the reads and writes in step 6 and 7 somehow get re-ordered to before step 5, stepping on another thread accessing shared data under protection of the mutex.

The `test_and_set` operation is already atomic, so steps 4 and 5 are inherently safe. And steps 1 and 2 can't modify protected data (because they occur before we even try to lock) so there's no harm in re-ordering them around our lock operation.

But steps 6 and 7 -- those must not be re-ordered to prior to us observing that the lock was unlocked so that we could atomically lock it. That would be a catastrophe.

The definition of memory_order_acquire: "*A load operation with this memory order performs the acquire operation on the affected memory location: no memory accesses in the current thread can be reordered before this load.*"

Exactly what we need.

Comment: "so steps 4 and 5 are inherently safe" no they are not. Atomic means indivisible writing and nothing else. They are no inherently safe. Other threads might still see old values. To add more "logic" all this `sync with` stuff were invented. Please, see the update to the question.

Comment: I guess the implicit assumption (which I think holds) is that an atomic 'test_and_set' operation also has a visible effect on other cores. Threads on the same core should see memory absolutely identical. Sometimes additional syncing is needed when haveing core local cache.

Comment: @JonasWolf I think on many architectures a test-and-set operation will generally have a visible result on other cores. But does the standard mandate this? This "implicit assumption" needs a reference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the purpose of a spinlock is that it _can_ run on multiple cores and guarantees that only one of them will enter the critical section at any given time. So "the code that runs on those other cores" is the same code. That is the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand that the "test and set" is atomic, the question is _what_ it is testing. Without `memory_order_acquire` (as in OP's code) it could test a value in the core's cache rather than the value in memory. But without making it a release operation, the set part of the operation might not be visible to other cores even though they use `memory_order_acquire`.  If, as you seem to believe, the test-and-set always bypasses the local cache, what is the purpose of using `memory_order_acquire` (and later `memory_order_release`) in the sample code?

Comment: Wait, I think I understand now. The acquire/release orderings are for writes/reads that occur to _other_ memory while the spinlock is held?

Comment: @davmac the problem is not about the 'test_and_set'. It is about other memory accesses that should be protected by the lock. Sorry, I read your comment too late. Yes, it is about other memory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz see my comment above - "Wait, I think I understand now. The acquire/release orderings are for writes/reads that occur to other memory while the spinlock is held?" From 29.3: _Atomic operations specifying memory_order_relaxed are relaxed with respect to memory ordering. Implementations must still guarantee that any given atomic access to a particular atomic object be indivisible with respect to all other atomic accesses to that object_ - this completely supports your answer, which I've now upvoted.

Comment: @ixSci "Other threads might still see old values." Sure, and to prevent that, other threads have to be coded correctly as well. If two threads, for example, are running the same "lock" operation code that we're talking about here, they're *both* using an atomic "test and set" operation, so there's no risk that one thread's read can occur in the middle of the other thread's read-modify-write. But sure, it's possible to imagine that another thread running broken code can trample on the logic of this code's operation. However, the lock and unlock operations here are careful.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, atomic only prevents torn reads nothing else. And for the aforementioned `lock` to not allow 2+ threads to enter it simultaneously  should somehow guarantee that 2 operations are ordered. And I don't see how they are ordered, could you please show me how they are ordered with C++ terms(happens-before, sync with etc.)?

Comment: @ixSci They don't need to be ordered, just atomic. The only problem would be one thread modifying the value after another thread had read it but before it modified it. It is impossible for two atomic operations read-modify-writes not to be ordered -- if one does something "during" the other one, then the other one was not atomic.

Comment: @ixSci And, most importantly, atomic doesn't just prevent torn reads, it makes the read-modify-write operation atomic. (That is, be indivisible and effectively all take place at the same time.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, so, according to you if we have `locked.test_and_set(memory_order_relaxed)` in T1 and later in time(1ns later, for example) we have `locked.test_and_set(memory_order_relaxed)` T2 then we are guaranteed to see the flag set in T2?

Comment: @ixSci Let's start with a very basic point: Do you agree that if two operations are atomic, then they cannot partially overlap or intertwine -- either one comes before the other or they both completely occur at the same time (this is the definition of atomic -- all at once). And do you agree that two atomic read-modify-write operations to precisely the same memory address cannot occur at the same time (basic sanity of atomic read-modify-write operations)? Once you agree with those two points, a yes answer to your question follows immediately.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to say but you completely misunderstand the C++ execution  model. So I don't see any point to continue this discussion. No offense, but your view is just wrong. If you don't believe me then just check the [following code](https://goo.gl/siajRA). Look at the asm output for ARM and PowerPC you will find no `dmb` for the first, and `sync` for the second. Then uncomment the more restricted lines and then you will find `dmb` and `sync` instructions. You don't need to understand asm of these machines(I don't) you just need to find these instructions - they are memory barriers.

Comment: @ixSci That is perfectly consistent with my point. Yes, the atomic test and set operation is atomic, always. If you *also* need memory barriers, you can request them. That's the entire point I'm explaining in my answer. Atomic, always. Memory barriers, if needed in the use case you can ask for them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79928/discussion-between-ixsci-and-david-schwartz).

Comment: My investigation led me to the conclusion that you are right and I'm wrong. Thank you for the discussion because it helped me much - it shaked my conviction :) I set +1 to this post and marked @davmac's post as an answer because his post have more C++ish info for the subject and it is good for those who later stumble onto this post. Thank you guys, I eradicated one silly misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `test_and_set` is a RMW operation. However, for testing it is only important that the correct value is read. Thus, `memory_order_acquire` seems sufficient.

See also table `Constants` in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: That I know. I don't understand why people use `std::memory_order_acquire`

Comment: You are right. I didn't read your question thoroughly enough. Please have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: I don't see how we can assert that correct value is read while we have 2 unordered operations. As far as I understand 2 `acquire` operations are no more related than 2 `relaxed` operations. Both operations do writing and neither syncs with another.

Comment: Another try (sorry, I find it hard to explain): For a lock operation, you need `test_and_set` operation. The `test_and_set` operation is usually atomic. So the only thing we need to ensure is that memory writes prior to `test_and_set` are not reordered. "This ensures that all writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread." So, if one thread has acquired the lock, the "test" operation in the other threads "fail" and do not lead to a set, because the write is definitely visible there.

Comment: Can you write what do you mean in C++ standard terms? Because I still don't why we have any guarantees here. Let `test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)` be operation A in T1 and B in T2. Then I do not see any *happens before* relationship between them, they just don't form any as far as I understand. Standard aside: let these operations have `read_barrers` before execution. Both of them can put `locked` into `write buffers` of the corresponding CPUs and I don't see what prevents CPU from doing it provided we are giving only an acquire(aka read barrier) operation.

Comment: Consider a `test_and_set` (your A in T1). If a load in a following critical operation `do_critical` would be reordered so it is executed before the `test_and_set`, we had a problem.
The `lock` operation of your example could also be named `acquire lock`. This matches the `memory_order_acquire`, where the `test_and_set` operation is the acquiring of the lock.

Comment: @ixSci You're ignoring the fact that the operation are atomic. Two atomic operations cannot partially overlap by the very definition of "atomic".