# Atomic bool fails to protect non-atomic counter

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, atomic

I encountered an issue with a (basic) spinlock mutex that does not seem to work as expected.

4 threads are incrementing a non-atomic counter that is protected by this mutex.
The outcome does not match with the expected result which makes the mutex seem broken.

example output:

```
  result: 2554230
expected: 10000000
```

In my environment it happens under the following conditions:

- `flag` is `std::atomic<bool>`, anything else such as `std::atomic<int>` or `std::atomic_flag` (with `test_and_set`) works fine.
- compiled on X86_64 with gcc 6.3.1 and `-O3` flag

My question is, what could explain this behavior ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <assert.h>

class my_mutex {
    std::atomic<bool> flag{false};

public:
    void lock()
    {
        while (flag.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire));
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        flag.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    }
};


my_mutex mut;
static int counter = 0;


void increment(int cycles)
{
    for (int i=0; i < cycles; ++i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<my_mutex> lck(mut);

        ++counter;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> vec;
    const int n_thr = 4;
    const int n_cycles = 2500000;

    for (int i = 0; i < n_thr; ++i)
        vec.emplace_back(increment, n_cycles);

    for(auto &t : vec)
        t.join();

    std::cout << "  result: " << counter << std::endl;
    std::cout << "expected: " << n_cycles * n_thr << std::endl;
}
```

### edit

Per request from Voo, here is the assembly output for `increment()`..

```
$ g++ -O3 increment.cpp
$ gdb a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) disassemble increment
Dump of assembler code for function increment(int):
   0x0000000000401020 <+0>:     mov    0x20122a(%rip),%ecx        # 0x602250 <_ZL7counter>
   0x0000000000401026 <+6>:     test   %edi,%edi
   0x0000000000401028 <+8>:     mov    $0x1,%edx
   0x000000000040102d <+13>:    lea    (%rdi,%rcx,1),%esi
   0x0000000000401030 <+16>:    jle    0x401058 <increment(int)+56>
   0x0000000000401032 <+18>:    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000401038 <+24>:    mov    %edx,%eax
   0x000000000040103a <+26>:    xchg   %al,0x20120c(%rip)        # 0x60224c <mut>
   0x0000000000401040 <+32>:    test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000401042 <+34>:    jne    0x401038 <increment(int)+24>
   0x0000000000401044 <+36>:    add    $0x1,%ecx
   0x0000000000401047 <+39>:    cmp    %ecx,%esi
   0x0000000000401049 <+41>:    mov    %ecx,0x201201(%rip)        # 0x602250 <_ZL7counter>
   0x000000000040104f <+47>:    movb   $0x0,0x2011f6(%rip)        # 0x60224c <mut>
   0x0000000000401056 <+54>:    jne    0x401038 <increment(int)+24>
   0x0000000000401058 <+56>:    repz retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Yakk has answered your question, but I am curious. Why are you attempting to write your own mutex?

Comment: @mascoj Absolutely not :)  This is just some messing around; anything like this should never be used in real code

Comment: I think that to ensure you yourself understand it, you should write it in some prover system for concurrency, and have the prover give you counterexamples where the invariants break.

Comment: Sure looks like a bug if the problem persists even with sequential memory ordering (memory_order_acq_rel should be all that's needed for the lock). Assembly would be interesting to see what happens.

Comment: Well, the assembly shows what is happening. It reads `counter` once at the beginning of the thread, and while it writes it repeatedly with incremented values, the incremented values are from the cached original contents of `counter`, so effectively, the final `counter` value is whatever the last thread to write saw when it cached `counter`, plus the number of cycles that thread performed.

Comment: I believe this behavior explicitly violates the requirements of `std::memory_order_acquire`, which mandates that no reads or writes in the current thread (of any variable, atomic or not) can be reordered before the load in question, yet `counter` is being loaded before the loop even begins.

Comment: Removing the `static` from `counter` makes it work. Also, using `short` and `unsigned char` for the atomic breaks just like `bool`; `int` and `long` don't. Interesting...

Comment: @ShadowRanger interesting observation.. Does this boil down to a bug in gcc ?

Comment: Works unchanged with trunk GCC on Wandbox and breaks with their GCC 6.3 too, so definitely looks like a bug that has been fixed since.

Comment: @T.C. more...in Wandbox earlier versions up to 5.4 give the correct outcome. Then it breaks and gets fixed in current trunk (gcc HEAD 7.0.1 20170207).

Comment: @LWimsey Wrt your comment on the deleted post: The acquire/release order is essential (not on x86 due to its strong ordering guarantees) since there absolutely *is* data that other threads have to read: your write to the flag. And that only works if the read has acquire semantics and writes release - otherwise other threads might not see the write. A release without acquire is never useful and since exchange reads and writes you need both.

Comment: @Voo The minimal, required ordering is what I specified in my question source, necessary even on X86 since nothing keeps the compiler from reordering statements with the mutex if relaxed ordering is used.
_If_ the compiler does not reorder anything with the mutex, then yes the X86 implicit Acquire/Release semantics will save the day...
About your comment that the required ordering must be `acq_rel` instead of `acquire`-only in `lock()`: This is not true and has nothing to do with other threads reading the atomic variable. .....

Comment: ..... `flag` is atomic and _will_ be seen by other threads regardless of the used memory ordering.
Atomicity guarantees that there is _always_ a well-defined _happens-before_ ordering wrt operations on a single atomic variable.
If the flag is modified, it _will_ be seen immediately by `exchange` in other threads.
Ordering constraints are meaningless wrt the individual atomic loads and stores because there is nothing to order; it's just the atomic variable itself being modified.
They come into play for memory access before (in program order) and after the atomic operations .....

Comment: ..... and that is exactly why you need a `release` barrier for `unlock()` (to prevent operations from moving down across that barrier)
and an `acquire`-only barrier for `lock()` (to prevent operations from moving up across the barrier).
An `acq_rel` barrier on an RMW would _only_ be necessary if you were updating other (unrelated) data before the RMW call (`release`),
while another thread would have to act upon that same data after calling the same RMW (`acquire`) .....

Comment: ..... In that case there has to be a causal chain of events that is guaranteed by `acq_rel`, but this does not apply to my (simple) mutex since it only operates on a single atomic flag in the loop,
which will be visible immediately to `exchange` in other threads; there are no other data dependencies.
Note that if the mutex did not have to protect any data, then even `relaxed` ordering would be fine.
The mutex could be reordered with anything and would be completely useless, but each thread would still observe the current value of `flag` atomically and only one at a time would see `false`.

Comment: @LWimsey "If the flag is modified, it will be seen immediately by exchange in other threads." and that's where you're wrong with your current code. A write with memory_order_acquire is the same as a write with no memory order at all since acquire only makes sense for reads. Hence you're writing with no memory order to a value and reading with acquire which has no meaning without a relevant release store. The only guarantee you have when reading with acquire is that you will see writes with release or stronger guarantee.

Comment: @Voo I agree that `acquire` applies to loads only, which means that `acquire` on the `exchange` RMW uses no ordering for the store part. Therefore, I also agree that my `exchange` RMW writes with no specified memory order.
However, at that point no memory ordering is necessary for the store since the only thing other threads need to observe is the latest value of `flag`; there is no other data to release.
The acquire part, however, is necessary because it protects memory operations that follow the mutex `lock()` from moving out of the protected area....

Comment: ....Ordering is by definition guaranteed on a single atomic variable: If I update an atomic variable,
and that _happens-before_ another thread calling an RMW, that thread _will_ see the latest value, even with relaxed ordering.
You seem to believe that a release operation is necessary in order to make the flag value visible to other threads, but this is not true.

Comment: @Voo Imagine a simple atomic counter that has no data dependencies, it is only incremented by concurrent threads.
Each thread would then call an RMW (such as `fetch_add(1, relaxed)` and after all threads have joined (an implicit acq/rel barrier), the counter value would be the number of times it was incremented.
This is guaranteed to work with `relaxed`. It is absolutey not necessary to specify `ack/rel` to make the counter update visible to other threads.

Comment: Just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691135/basic-spin-lock-mutex-implementation-ordering/30692887), which basically contains the same discussion as we are having - 
I found the answer by @David Schwartz about acquire interesting

Comment: @LWimsey Oh very interesting, thanks for finding that link.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I want to put everything together in an answer. Can I quote your comments (about the assembly) in my answer ?

Comment: @LWimsey: Be my guest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. It's a [bug 80004](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80004) - [6 Regression] non-atomic load moved to before atomic load with std::memory_order_acquire